# Identifying numbers that have the same given HCF and LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Two numbers have a highest common factor of $12$ and a lowest common multiple of $600$. Besides $12$ and $600$ themselves , find another pair of numbers that fulfill the above condition .

I'm not sure how to carry on from my working -
$$HCF= 2^2 \times 3 = 12\;\;\;\&\;\;\;
LCM= 2^3 \times 3 \times 5^2 = 600 $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $a,b$ are your two numbers, then they are both divisible by $12$.

Write 
$$a=12k \\
b=12l$$
with $k,l$ relatively prime.

Then 
$$gcd(k,l)=1 \\
12kl=lcm(a,b)=600$$
Therefore $kl=50$.

The problem thus reduces to writing $50$ as the product of two **relatively prime** numbers $k,l$.

Answer (score 0):

so your pair of numbers both have 2*2*3 as a factor. you know that one of them must have 5^2 as a factor - if both had 5 as a factor, the HCF would be 60.

let these numbers be denoted a and b - a = 2*2*3 * .., b= 2*2*3 * 5*5 * ... 
one number must include 2^3 - so we divide both numbers by their common factor of 12, and find that

50 = ab, and b contains 5^2, or 25 - 
so a(b/25) = 2 , so either a or b contains 2^3.

thus, your candidates are 
a = 2^3 *3 = 24 or 2^2 * 3 = 12
b = 2^2 * 3 * 5^2 = 300 , and b = 2^3*3*5^2 =600

so your pairs are 24,30 or 12,600

Answer (score 0):

There is a general method. Write
$$
\begin{cases}
12 = 2^{2} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{0}\\
600 = 2^{3} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Now exchange at pleasure the powers of a fixed prime between the two lines. In this case, you can exchange the two powers of $2$ obtaining
$$
\begin{cases}
24 = 2^{3} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{0}\\
300 = 2^{2} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Exchanging the two powers of $5$ will give the same result.
Can you see why this method gives you all the possibilities?

**Hint**

> Think of the definition of gcd and lcm in terms of factorizations.

Answer (score 0):

We want to find natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $gcd(a,b)=12$ and $lcm(a,b)=600$.

Let $a_p$ be the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $a$. Analogously for $b$.

Then all pairs $a,b$ come from solutions of

$\min(a_2,b_2)=2,\qquad \max(a_2,b_2)=3$

$\min(a_3,b_3)=1,\qquad \max(a_3,b_3)=1$

$\min(a_5,b_5)=0,\qquad \max(a_5,b_5)=2$

Therefore

$(a_2,b_2) \in \{ (2,3), (3,2) \}$

$(a_3,b_3) \in \{ (1,1) \}$

$(a_5,b_5) \in \{ (0,2), (2,0) \}$

a total of $2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 4$ solutions, $2$ if we ignore order, and we're left with $a=24$ and $b=300$.